# Web page which passes variables to shell script

Tags: php, shell, cgi

I currently use a shell script we use to move data around, which is run with the following syntax:

```
./script.sh <env> <y|n> <file> <file> <file> <file> <file> <file> 

$1 sets a variable for production/test
$2 sets a variable whether we perform a tarball of the destination folder before copying
$3 - $# is a space delimited list of files to move (there has to be a minimum of one file, no maximum)
```

I need to pass this script to a different user, but don't trust him with shell access to the box.

What I'd like to do is create a web page with three fields. Field one is a radio button of the environment, which will be passed as $1. Field two is a radio button of yes/no, which I'd like passed as $2. And Field 3 is a multiselect box, which I'd like to be populated from either a static text file, or (preferably) from running an "ls" over the source directory - this will be $3+

Is this possible? I can run Apache on the server so PHP or even CGI will be available.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. It will be run as the web servers user however.

Just use `system()` or `exec()` to call your bash script.

Documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Make sure to use `escapeshellarg()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php to get rid of unwanted input.. Perhaps write your own blacklist as well.

Example:

```
$script_path = '/path/to/script.sh';
system( $script_path . ' ' . $argument );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_POST)) { //more tests required here...
    exec('sh /path/to/shell ' . $_POST['var1'] . ' '  . $_POST['var2'] . ' '  . $_POST['var3']);
  }
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php